# What effect does feeling Well Rested have?

Tags: fallout-4

After sleeping, you'll receive a message stating that "You feel Well Rested":

[image: You feel well rested]

What effect does feeling Well Rested have?

Comment: I was expecting this to be about Skyrim for some reason.

Comment: Same name, same effect as Skyrim. http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Rest_(Skyrim)

Comment: This also appeared in (at least some) previous Fallouts.

Comment: This actually appeared in Fallout 3, Fallout New Vegas, and now this one too, along with Skyrim.  It is quite literally the same effect.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well Rested is a temporary perk that gives you a 10% XP bonus for a period of time. The wiki lists this period as being 12 hours. You can see the perk on the perks page in your Pip-Boy.

[Source](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Well_Rested_%28perk%29)

Comment: I didn't get the source's message ("You had a great sleep, and feel alert and invigorated! +10% XP earned") upon waking—does anyone else get it? It also apparently doesn't affect the INT stat.

Comment: The message is listed under the "Perks" section when you receive this temporary buff.  As for the INT stat, no idea where you thought Well Rested affects INT.

Comment: @Sean That's because that was the wrong link. It was for previous Fallout games. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

To add on to the previous answer, You have to sleep in a bed that you own for one hour and you will get the +10% experience for 8 hours in game.

Comment: "for 8 hours in game." [the wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Well_Rested) says 12 hours in-game time.

Comment: The wiki also says you can sleep for zero hours to get the bonus. @FuriousFolder, I ask about the length in this other question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/253559/108003

Comment: @DCShannon if you check the revision history of that page  ( http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Well_Rested_(perk)?diff=2488426&oldid=2486911 ) you'll see that this information was added *after* I made that comment.

Comment: @FuriousFolder Okay, cool. Not sure how that's relevant to anything, but sure.