# What are the benefits and drawbacks of sleeping?

Tags: fallout-4

In games I generally avoid sleeping in beds... I can do that in real life. But other than healing, is there a benefit to sleeping?

Also is there a downside to sleeping?

Comment: I'm interested in the second part about drawbacks.. specifically anything negative that can happen if you're resetting the map by resting for 30 days.

Answer (score 8):

Sleeping will give you the "Well Rested" state, [which increases your experience gain by 10%](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242680/52800).

It also allows you to skip time in game so you can wait for Supply Routes to set up for the first time or skip ahead to the daylight for the various daylight perks like Solar Powered (or night time perks like Night Person, if you've gone for those).

Comment: You will only receive the 'Well rested' buff if you sleep in a bed you own, such as in a settlement you control.

Comment: You can also skip time by sitting in any unowned chair. A "wait" option will become available.

Comment: So there's no 'rested' bonus from sleeping in unoccupied beds like in Skyrim?

Comment: You can get the bonus by resting 0 hours, avoiding any possible downside. No, @IG_42 there isn't. However, you can get the Lover's Embrace perk by sleeping in any bed near your romantic companion. Also, Kalina, Supply Routes are ready instantly. I mostly pass time so stores will open or so I can sneak somewhere in the dark.

Answer (score 3):

In Survival Mode, sleeping allows you to:

- save your game.
- stay healthy (you need to sleep normaly).
- healing Hit Points if you sleep 8 hours.

Downside effects:

- You lose some ranks of your [Adrenaline](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Adrenaline) perk.
- You will often wake up thirsty and hungry.