# How long do sleeping bonuses last?

Tags: fallout-4

You can temporarily gain the [Well Rested perk](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Well_Rested_%28perk%29), adding +10% experience, by sleeping in an owned bed. You can instead temporarily gain the [Lover's Embrace perk](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lover's_Embrace), adding +15% experience, by sleeping in any bed with a romantic companion nearby.

**How long do these bonuses last?**

I've heard 12 hours, which is listed on both those Nukapedia pages, but it doesn't always seem to be true. Checking the in-game clock, I've fast traveled to somewhere less than 7 hours away and lost the bonus.

**What actions will cause them to end prematurely?**

I know that sleeping in any bed will you cause you to lose Well Rested. Will anything else cause these perks to end early?

Answer (score 1):

I tested Lover's Embrace by getting the perk in Sanctuary, noting the time, and then traveling to various locations. In every instance, I still had the perk less than 8 hours from getting it, and didn't after more than 8 hours.

For example, the Boston Airport is more than 8 hours away. I lose the bonus when I fast travel there. Bunker Hill is less than 8 hours away. I still have the bonus when I travel there. If I travel to Bunker Hill, and then to the Boston Airport, I have the bonus at Bunker Hill, but have lost it by the time I reach the Airport.

Therefore, **Lover's Embrace lasts for 8 hours**. I assume Well-Rested lasts the same.

Comment: I would accept this, but I never got around to testing Well Rested to confirm that they work the same.

Comment: Another user had a pretty comprehensive answer for Well-Rested, think it was Timelord. Think he rage quit the site. He tested, and found 8 hours was correct for that as well.

Answer (score -3):

You lose the buff if you fast travel. I'm not sure of the exact number it lasts, in Skyrim it lasted for 8 hours so I doubt it would be any different to that.

Comment: Are you sure you're losing it due to Fast Travel, or are you just losing it because of the time that passes during Fast Travel to certain locations? Remember, Fast Travel is not actually instantaneous.

Comment: You can test it by going to camps within a short distance and the time difference won't be that large and it'll disappear. It's stupid but that's apparently how it works.

Comment: No. The action of fast traveling does not remove the buff. Go to Sanctuary and fast travel to it or the Red Rocket truck stop; the buff will still be there. It does last 8 hours though.

Comment: Although I've lost it sooner than I thought I would fast traveling, I've also kept it fast traveling. This is incorrect.

Comment: @infek, why would it copy Skyrim, and not the previous Fallout games? Fast travel does not necissarily negate the well rested, but it does move time forward with the travel. If time moves past the expiry, the effect expires.